# I wish to create a custom event on basis of the existence of dataLayer Variable existes in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, eventtrigger

I tried few options that if dataLayer Variable like for example ABC contains .* or matches regex .* but nothing works. It either fires on all the cases or it doesent fire at all. I want a custom trigger that if a particular datalayer variable exists with any value that the trigger should be fired or it should not get fired.

Comment: Can you please post the screenshots of your tag configurations in GTM? What you should have is a variable which is a Data Layer type, and you can just create a trigger that uses that variable, and checks if it exists or not.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/89d5tw. I want that if this dataLayer appears on the page, then only the trigger gets fired. If dataLayer does not appear it should not get fired.